# tensorflow typed miss when run my train.py

Tags: tensorflow

It will report 
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, or numpy ndarrays. when run my tensorflow code
Is there some bug below my code? I have convert tensor type by using feed_dict types.Why it still failed?

```
 with tf.Session() as sess:
                tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
                coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
                threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
                print('Initialized!')
                for step in xrange(150000):
                        data,label = read_data(FLAGS.train_file)
                        feed_dict = {train_data_node: data,
                                     train_labels_node: label}
                        _, l, lr, predictions = sess.run([optimizer, loss_value, learning_rate, train_prediction],feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: Can you share the code for your `read_data()` function? It looks like it is returning a `tf.Tensor` object (or two), whereas it might not need to.

Answer (score 1):

The error says:  The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor

Your feed is:

```
feed_dict = {train_data_node: data,
    train_labels_node: label}
```

Thus, one (or both) between `data` & `label` are `tf.Tensor` object.

You have to extract the value into this object, obtaining an acceptable value for a feed.

To do this, you have to `run` (or `eval`) the object before passing it to the feed.

**Tl;dr:**

```
feed_dict = {train_data_node: data.eval(),
    train_labels_node: label.eval()}
```